# PyQt5 matplotlib retina resolution

Tags: python, macos, qt, matplotlib, pyqt5

I'm trying to draw real time plots with Python and matplotlib in a Qt5 application. I managed to create the windows, plot the canvas, and update my plot (1-2 times in a second), with the [modified PyQt4 tutorial](http://www.boxcontrol.net/embedding-matplotlib-plot-on-pyqt5-gui.html).

The application have retina resolution (so, the buttons/texts are pixel perfect), but not the matplotlib canvas.

I tried to set the width and height (only affects drawing area size), and dpi (only affects font sizes, but not sharpness). I'm using a Python 3.5 virtualenv, installed with brew.

I read, that adding

```
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
<true/>
```

to the applications `Info.plist` file should solve this, but it didn't. (Tried with py2app, and manual editing the file)

Any suggestions how to render high resolution plots, in an application, and how to configure it in Pycharm (or any other IDE)?

Comment: Running the PyQt5 example on a Macbook with the latest version of the Anaconda distribution produces the same issue: high resolution buttons on the window, but low-resolution plots. http://matplotlib.org/1.5.0/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt5.html